# c++ summation using for loop and two dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, sum

I'm trying to create a loop that calculates the total book sales for each year. I also need to calculate the total book sales for the last three years.

I have worked out how to calculate the sum of all 3 years however, I am having trouble with the calculation for total book orders sold each year. Here is what I have so far.

```
    const int months = 12;
    const int years =3;
    string namonths [months] = {"January", "February", "March", "April",
                 "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                 "October", "November", "December"};
int bookorders[years][months];
int sum=0;

for (int i = 0; i < years ; i++) {
for (int n = 0; n < months; n++) {

    std::cout << "Year " << i + 1 << " Month " << namonths[n] <<":"<< std::endl;

    cin >> bookorders[i][n];

    sum += bookorders[i][n];
}

}

//  std::cout << "total orders are for each year are: " << sum <<std::endl;
std::cout << "total orders are " << sum <<std::endl;
```

Comment: You're using `namonths` as a `string` and as an array index - does this even compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a new variable which stores the sums per year:
   `int sumPerYear[years];`
2. Between the two for statements:
   `sumPerYear[i] = 0;`
3. Then in the for loop core say:
   `sumPerYear[i] += bookorders[i][n];`
4. Finally at the end:
   `for (int i = 0; i < years ; i++) 
        std::cout << "year " << i << " sum: " << sumPerYear[i] << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

Here try this. sumperYear is variable that is initially zero. In every iteration of the outer 
for loop, the sumperYear will be displayed.

`for (int i=0; i<years; i++)
    {
         for (int j=0 ; j< months; j++)
             {
                sumperYear+=bookOrders[i][j];
             }
       cout<<"For the year:" << i+1 << " the total orders are: "<< sumperYear;
       sumperYear=0;
}`